# How To Share two computers Via WiFi Without Wi-Fi Router

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

How to share two computers via wifi without wi-fi router?

I tried but was not successful.

I was following  below steps -

- I created an ad hoc network connect another computer from this network
- Create a homegroup in both computers
- After creating homegroup in both computer I did not get join homegroup option for sharing files

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple shared folder on the host machine?

Comment: I have created shared folder but i want to share it another computer through wifi without router or internet

Comment: Just to confirm, does the other computer have a wireless receiver?

Answer (score 0):

To create an ad-hoc network, follow the following steps :-
1. Type the following command in command prompt (Run As Administrator)
     netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=*networkname* key=*password*
2. Now type
     netsh wlan start hostednetwork
3. To see the status of the hosted network, type
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
4. Your ad hoc network would have started working when you completed step 2.

Troubleshoots :-
In case after completing step 3, you find the 'Hosted Network Status' as NOT AVAILABLE or after step 2, you get the error :-
'The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.'
Follow the following steps :-
1. Open Device Manager
2. Click on View and select 'Show hidden devices'
3. Expand Network Adapters
4. Check the status of 'Microsoft Wifi Direct Virtual Adapter' and Enable it if it is disabled.
5. Now repeat from step 2 of the previous paragraph. You will now find the 'Hosted Network Status' as Started.
6. Now connect other devices to this network by typing the password you specified in step 1 of previous paragraph in those devices.

For File Sharing options,
1. Open Network and sharing center.
2. Click the 'Change advanced sharing settings' link on the left.
3. Under File and Printer Sharing, Select the Turn On file and printer sharing.
4. Under Network Discovery, select Turn On network discovery.

This must solve your problem.
To stop the network, type 
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork in command prompt.
(NOTE :- Command Prompt must be Run As Administrator in all the steps)

Regards.

Comment: I have completed first step but when I am running second cooman for startup hostednetworhk it's showing following error.
"the hosted netwotk couldn't be started."
"The group of resource is not the correct state to peform the requested opretion."

Comment: Ok. Now follow the 'Troubleshoots' steps in Device Manager.